# Python 2.7 "requests" module on Fedora 19

Tags: python, python-2.7, fedora

When I'm trying to import `requests` module:

```
import requests
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
import requests
ImportError: No module named requests
```

How can I fix that on Fedora 19?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure u have done proper installation and set it in you PYTHONPATH ?

Comment: @Vivek: There's no reason he should need to set PYTHONPATH if he's done proper installation.

Answer (score 6):

`pip install requests` or `yum install python-requests`

Edit:

You can install it using fedora package manager (yum).
Or using pip (python package index) docs (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip). If you want to use pip then you must install pip first, `yum install python-pip`

I use pip, yum or apt packages are generally older than the ones on pip.

Comment: I'm not sure why this was downvoted. From the OP's brief description, it sounds like the most likely problem is that he just hasn't installed it, and this is the solution. It might benefit from a little explanation (e.g., why you'd want to do one vs. the other), and I think Fedora 19 doesn't come with `pip` preinstalled so you'd need `yum install python-pip` before doing the first version. But imperfect doesn't mean bad.

Comment: abarnert you are right, I have just added more information. Thanks